# How to generate column only if that column doesn't exist in Stata?

Tags: stata

I can create the variable `logincome` using

```
generate logincome = log(income)
```

But from the 2nd execution of do file, it shows me an error:

```
variable logincome already defined
```

If Stata were to ask me if I want to skip or overwrite it if the variable is already there, that would be great.

I tried to find some `if` statement of Stata to do this... like if `logincome` exists then the following line is skipped. But my googling didn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions to this type of problem. See `help confirm`, `help assert`, `help ifcmd`, etc. to start. However, a simple solution is

```
capture generate logincome = log(income)
```

`capture` will prevent your code from breaking if the command immediately following produces an error. Note also that `help capture` will assist in making use of `confirm`, `assert`, and the `if` command in other (more substantive) situations.

To take a step even further back, however, you may wish to start your do-file with `clear` and `use` statements, so that with each execution of the do-file you read in the unaltered data, and then perform the commands you have written.

Comment: @Brendan_Cox Thank you! By the way, I tried to use use statement as you suggested, and my dta file is in the same directory as do file, but      $$use "data.dta"$$  doesn't work. Specifying exact C://... location won't be a good idea since other people also need to be able to run it on their computer.

Comment: You've asked the quite different question in the comment above in a new question. Best to delete it therefore.